# Заполняющий футер у UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

У UITableView, если не указан `footerView`, по умолчанию незаполненное пространство заполняется пустыми ячейками. Мне нужно вместо ячеек сделать, чтобы свободное пространство заполнялось сплошным фоном. Как это сделать? Т.е., если содержимое таблицы меньше вьюшки таблицы, то надо заполнить оставшееся пространство до нижнего края экрана определенным цветом.

Comment: Есть простой способ, но при этом панель с батарейкой и часами (которая наверху), будет такого же цвета. То есть если какой-то серый цвет, не сильно отличающийся от цвета таблицы, то это еще ничего.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос следующим образом:

```
let myBackgroundView = UIView()
view.addSubview(myBackgroundView)
myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = view.backgroundColor
myTable.tableHeaderView = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()
myTable.tableHeaderView?.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.top.equalToSuperview().priority(.medium)
    make.left.right.equalTo(view)
}
myBackgroundView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.top.left.right.equalToSuperview()
    make.bottom.equalTo(profileTable.tableHeaderView!.snp.top)
}
```

Да, вместо футера сделал хэдер, но сути особо это не меняет.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вот так:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    view.backgroundColor = .yellow
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, вы все правильно поняли. Однако, предложенный вами способ не подходит, т.к. при свайпе вниз сверху также будет виден этот фон.

Comment: Это я и имел ввиду :(

Comment: Так в чем проблема, задизейблите свайп и все. Или свайп тоже нужен? Тогда сделайте футер нужного размера и установите его фон. Или сделайте вьюху после таблицы и установите ее фон.

Comment: Свайп у таблицы нужен, поскольку контент динамичный. Футер статичной высоты не подойдет, поскольку пользователь может натягивать таблицу как угодно. Вьюха после таблицы не подойдет, поскольку она будет просто уменьшать размер страницы, а не скроллиться вместе с ней.

Comment: Еще вариант - заполняйте пустые ячейки (без возможности выделения) нужным цветом и убирайте у них сепаратор, будет видимость пустого пространства нужного цвета.